# ASP.NET - How to send data on a button

Tags: asp.net, object, post, button, model-view-controller

I am using a sample project for ASP.NET using MVC. I am very new to ASP and would like some help with something I would like to do.

I have a List of Dogs in a 'vet surgey' this is very basic at the moment.

This list of dogs is shown in a table formatted like so;

`

```
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Breed</th>
                <th scope="col">Colour</th>
                <th scope="col">Age</th>
                <th scope="col">Health</th>
                <th scope="col"></th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach(var dog in Model){
                <tr>
                    <td>@dog.identity</td>
                    <td>@dog.Name</td>
                    <td class="">@dog.Breed</td>
                    <td>@dog.Colour</td>
                    <td>@dog.Age</td>
                    <td class="@dog.healthColour">@dog.dogHealthStatus</td>
                    <td>A button here to load an edit page for that dog</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

`

What I would like to do is for every row in the table, have an ability to click a button that opens a separate page to edit that particular dog.

This shouldn't be too difficult as all I would need is the dogs.ID passing into the function of the IActionResult for that particular row.

Am I going about this all wrong?

Is there an easier way?

I have tried using a line like this;
`

```
<td>
                        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  asp-controller="Home" asp-action="editDog">
                            <input style="visibility: hidden" type="text" id="dogID" name="dogID" placeholder="@dog.identity"/>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
                        </form>
                    </td>
```

`

Comment: If the only functionality is to direct the user to another page then why not simply a link?

Comment: I want the redirection to pre-populate another page with that dogs attributes pre-populated.

Answer (score 1):

> that opens a separate page to edit that particular dog

If the functionality is just to navigate the user to another page, you may be over-thinking it.  A *link* already performs exactly that functionality.  For example:

```
<a href="/Home/editDog?id=@dog.identity">Edit</a>
```

Or to generate the route with tag helpers:

```
<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="editDog" asp-route-id="@dog.identity">Edit</a>
```

However you build the link, the intent is that it navigates the user to the target route with the identifier for the "dog" being edited.  That target page would then use that identifier to populate its form.